# How can I check if an Ethereum address is valid by using zod parser?

Tags: ethers.js, clients, typescript, parser

How to parse an Ethereum address that was provided by a user with the help of zod [`safeParse()`](https://zod.dev/?id=safeparse) function?

Answer (score 3):

From zod docs:

> Zod lets you provide custom validation logic via refinements.

In order to achieve this you may want first to define a zod schema by using the [`refine()`](https://zod.dev/?id=refine) function in combination with [`ethers`](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/):

```js
const ethAddressSchema = z.string()
    .refine((value) => ethers.utils.isAddress(value), {
        message: "Provided address is invalid. Please insure you have typed correctly.",
    });
```

After that implement a basic validation:

```js
const result = ethAddressSchema.safeParse("0xd8dA6BF26964aF9D7eEd9e03E53415D37aA96045");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`custom`](https://zod.dev/?id=custom-schemas) in combination with `isAddress` from ethers ([v5](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/address/#utils-isAddress), [v6](https://docs.ethers.org/v6-beta/api/address/#isAddress)).

```typescript
import { isAddress } from 'ethers'; // ethers v6
import { z } from 'zod';


const Address = z.custom<string>(isAddress, "Invalid Address")

// Parse a value
Address.parse("0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2");
Address.parse("abc"); // throws error

// Use in another Schema
const Token = z.object({ address: Address });
Token.parse({ address: "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2" });
Token.parse({ address: "abc" }); // throws error
```